# Stripe stating no signatures found for the expected payload

Tags: typescript, express, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am creating a checkout session using stripe that on a success or completed session, will trigger my webhoo. It is reaching the webhook but i keep getting an error stating  "error": "No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? [https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing"](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing%22) here is my code.

```
const stripeRouter = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });

const endPointSecret = 'Webook_Secret'

stripeRouter.post('/webhook',
express.raw({type: 'application/json'}),
async (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const stripe = await getStripe();
  await getStripeSecretKey();

  const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
  console.log(`signature: ${sig}`)
  const payload = req.body;
  console.log(`payload: ${payload}`)

    let eventType;
    let data;

  if (endPointSecret) {
    let event;
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endPointSecret);
      console.log(`$$$$$ Webhook Verification Successful`)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`$$$$$ Webhook signature verification failed`, err.message)
      res.status(400).json({error: err.message, signature: req.body});
      return;
    }

    eventType = event.type;
    data = event.data;
    console.log(`$$$ EVENT TYPE: ${eventType}`)
    console.log(`$$$ DATA: ${data}`)
  } else {
    data = req.body.data.object;
    eventType = req.body.type;
  }
```

I have checked the webhook Signing Secret and that is correct. I have also tried using express.raw() and bodyParser.raw() but neither have worked. I continue to get the same error.

I also tried adding this piece of custom middleware to see if it would function, but continue to get the error

```
stripeRouter.use((req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
    next();`your text`
  } else {
    express.json()(req, res, next);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Webhook signature validation can be tricky here.  The first culprit to inspect is the webhook secret.  I know you said you have already checked it but it is worth pointing out that there are **separate** secrets for both Test and Live mode so you may want to double check that.

Also I would log the `endPointSecret` value *just prior* to attempting to construct the event to be absolutely sure the value you expect is being passed to the `constructEvent()` function.

If your endpoint secret is exactly what you expect and this is still failing then the issue is likely with the data payload.  It may seem like a lot of work but I would first try copyinng the [example webhook verification app](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/tree/master/examples/webhook-signing/express) for `stripe-node`.  Get it running and working and then start modifying the code and test step by step.  This should allow you to determine the exact change that causes the verification to fail.